# Make a python function that takes initial guess and parameters to produce guesses that terminate at single value

Tags: python, algorithm, function

Trying to make a function that takes an initial guess and 3 other parameters in order to produce guesses that converge to a single value.

Trying to make a python function that takes 4 arguments:

- a python function which accepts a number as an input, and returns a float as an output. Using this one: `def f(x): return  2 - exp(-x)`
- an initial guess for the fixed-point, a floating-point number
- a tolerance value, a positive-valued floating-point number
- a max number of iterations that algorithm is permitted to run

To measure how close a recent guess is to a fixed-point, I take the 3 most recent values and use this equation (`zap` is the list being accessed in this case): `caltol = abs(((zap[-1]-zap[-2])**2)/((2*zap[-2])-zap[-3]-zap[-1]))`

This is the code I have already tried but seems to get out-of-range errors in `nugget = mega[len(mega)-numms]`. Also when using some values for parameters the code fails to return the correct values, one example is `guess_finder(f, xo=83.30748524231714, tol=0.0013756415772893204, max_it=232)` should return `[83.30748524231714, 2.0, 1.8646647167633872]` but instead returns `[83.30748524231714, 2.0, 1.8646647167633872, 1.8450518473052135, 1.8419828720850022]`

Another example: running `guess_finder(f, xo=91.0, tol=1e-10, max_it=10)` should output `[91.0, 2.0, 1.8646647167633872, 1.8450518473052135, 1.8419828720850022, 1.8414971765224537, 1.8414201737059899, 1.8414079621425745, 1.8414060254740223, 1.8414057183297619]`

```
from math import exp
from collections import OrderedDict

def f(x):
    return  2 - exp(-x)

def guess_finder(func, xo, tol, max_it):
    legit=[]
    legit.append(xo)
    caltol = 0
    guesses = []

    mega = []    

    for x in range(max_it-1):
        xo = func(xo)
        legit.append(xo)  

    zap = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(legit))

    if max_it > 3 and len(zap) >= 3:
        mega = zap.copy()

        for i in range(len(zap)):
            print(caltol)
            caltol = abs(((zap[-1]-zap[-2])**2)/((2*zap[-2])-zap[-3]-zap[-1]))

            if caltol < tol:
                zap.pop()

    numms= len(mega)- len(zap)        
    if numms != 0 and numms > 0 :
        nugget = mega[len(mega)-numms]  
        zap.append(nugget)

    return zap
```

The function should produce guesses until  ϵn  is smaller than the specified tolerance value, or until the number of guesses produced (including the initial guess) matches/exceeds the max number of iterations. It should return a list of all the guesses. Will need to have three guesses before it can assess the tolerance.

Any help on this would be much appreciated. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Two modifications in your code -

1. in `for i in range(len(zap)):`, you need to stop at length - 2 for the cases where tolerance value is quite high, else it will go out of range - `for i in range(len(zap)-2):`
2. Add a condition when you have convergence much quicker than number of iterations -`if len(zap)>3: return zap[:3];`

Also, since you are ordering the list, this will work only if `x <f(x) or x>f(x)  for x in your space`.

Your full code will look like -

```
from math import exp
from collections import OrderedDict

def f(x):

    return  2 - exp(-x)

def guess_finder(func, xo, tol, max_it):

    legit=[]
    legit.append(xo)
    caltol = 0
    guesses = []

    mega = []    

    for x in range(max_it-1):
        xo = func(xo)
        legit.append(xo)  

    #print(legit)

    zap = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(legit))
    #print(legit)
    if max_it > 3 and len(zap) >= 3:
        mega = zap.copy()

        for i in range(len(zap)-2):
            print(caltol)
            caltol = abs(((zap[-1]-zap[-2])**2)/((2*zap[-2])-zap[-3]-zap[-1]))

            if caltol < tol:
                zap.pop()
    if len(zap)>3:
        print("test")
        return zap[:3]
    numms= len(mega)- len(zap)        
    if numms != 0 and numms > 0 :
        nugget = mega[len(mega)-numms]  
        zap.append(nugget)

    return zap
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @Aritesh, but when I run guess_finder(f, xo=91.0, tol=1e-10, max_it=10) the code returns  [91.0, 2.0, 1.8646647167633872]. However, the output should be [91.0, 2.0, 1.8646647167633872, 1.8450518473052135, 1.8419828720850022, 1.8414971765224537, 1.8414201737059899, 1.8414079621425745, 1.8414060254740223, 1.8414057183297619]

How do I fix this?

Comment: The code doesn’t seem to work^, can you help me fix this. Thanks.